# In Matplotlib, Python - Plotting the amplitude of .wav file on 3d axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have a very simple script which generates an amplitude plot from a .wav file as follows:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile # get the api

fs, data = wavfile.read('audio1.wav')    # load the data

plt.plot(data)  # plot the entire amplitude curve of the audio file

plt.show()
```

Resulting in the following:-

[Link to example image which the script outputs HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PtL5.jpg)

In this 2d image the data retrieved from the audio file provides values to plot for the x and y axes

I have been attempting to plot this on 3d axes, uasing this as my guide:-

http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.html

but I cannot seem to extract the values for the x and y axes satisfactorily to apply.

Any ideas??

Comment: it's does not make sense... the signal from your `.wav` file is two time (left and right, stereo) 2D signal, if you plot the signal you will plot y=f(x), if you want a 3D plot you need a third dimension...(which does not exist in this case...)

Comment: What are you expecting to see on the x, y and z axes?

Comment: I will see the x and y values as in the 2d plot displayed on a 3d axis - approximately like this:- https://www.researchgate.net/figure/230522332_fig3_Figure-7-Force-displacement-curves-of-SEN-TB-and-3D-contour-plots-showing-the

Comment: I would expect to create my own variable for the z axis. Then I will be able to plot multiple amplitude curves against one another for immediate visual comparison